# SAS and R survival package have different confidence interval estimates. Why?

Tags: r, survival, sas

Hello I am learning about Survival Analysis and I noticed that SAS and R `survival` package produce different confidence interval estimates for the median Survival times and I was curious why?

#### Generating my simulated data in R

```
set.seed(123)
library(survival)
size <-  100

deathtime <- rexp(size, rate = 1)
censor <- abs(rbinom(size, 1, .1) -1)



df <- data.frame(deathtime, censor)
#write.csv(df, "TestData.csv") #For uses in SAS
```

#### Using the Survival package

```
surv.obj <- Surv(df$deathtime, df$censor)

survfit(surv.obj ~ 1)
```

[image]

#### Using SAS

```
proc import datafile="P:\SAS\Interval\TestData.csv" out = test;
run;

PROC LIFETEST PLOTS=(S) METHOD=PL;                                                    
     TIME   deathtime *censor(0) ;                                                                                                                 
 RUN;
```

[image]

### Question

The point estimate is the same though the confidence intervals differs why?

Comment: Have you tried other transform? According to the `LIFETEST` procedure you can choose the transform using the `CONFTYPE` option https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/statug/15.2/statug_lifetest_syntax01.htm#statug.lifetest.lftmethod. More details regarding computation of the confidence interval are given on page 33 here https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/stat/141/lifetest.pdf

Comment: Yes @periwinkle as mentioned by EdM R has the `conf.type` argument to change the transform whose default is Log and SAS has the `CONFTYPE` to change the transform which default is log log. We figured it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to compute confidence intervals (CI) for survival curves. The SAS output suggests that it uses a log-log method based on $\log(-\log(\text{survival}))$.

Check the R documentation for `survfit.formula` to see its options for CI estimation. There is a default method for that function in R that isn't log-log. See what happens when you specify "log-log" as the method in R. Then, as suggested in a comment on your question, see what happens when you use SAS with different CI options.

Comment: Yes `survfit(surv.obj ~ 1, conf.type = "log-log")` Produced the same results as SAS

Comment: And adding a to SAS `CONFTYPE= LOG` leads to the same result in R.